# awk command to extract string after a specific pattern string

Tags: shell, awk

I want to extract the text after the pattern `"List values are here:"` that are in quotes in a list. I'm very new to this. Can someone please assist

```
List values are here: "list1 abc" "list2 test" "end of list"
```

What I have done:

```
echo $va| awk '/List values are here:/ {print $1}' var="$va"
```

Comment: as far as I understood, you have that text in a variable named `va`.. if so and if you are using a shell with parameter expansion, then `op="${va#*: }"` is what you are probably looking for.. if not, please add more details to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `awk` or `sed` for this kind of task since you only need to fetch some part of a line. `grep` is the tool you are looking for.

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=List values are here: ).*'
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$ echo 'List values are here: "list1 abc" "list2 test" "end of list"' | grep -oP '(?<=List values are here: ).*'
"list1 abc" "list2 test" "end of list"
```

after you can assign the result to a variable or do whatever you want with it.

**Explanations:**
 -  `-o` is to change the default behavior of `grep` which is outputting the whole line to outputting only the pattern
 -  `-P` is to use perl regex
 - `(?<=List values are here: ).*` regex to fetch everything after `List values are here:`

Comment: You should mention that `-P` is GNU-only and, according to their man page, "highly experimental" so YMMV...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "${val#*: }"
"list1 abc" "list2 test" "end of list"
```